# Pine Script V5 Max and Min Value in last n bars

Tags: pine-script

I want to draw 4 line on TradingView "Higiest Value Last 50 Bars , Higiest Closed Value Last 50 Bars , Lowest Value Last 50 Bars ,  Lowest Closed Value Last 50 Bars" like image. I find  ta.highest() only float series and i cant use with hline function. How can i find float numbers last 50 bars dynamically with periods timeframe Month Week Day Hour Minute .

[image]

I tried this code and i added float numbers manually

```
//@version=5
MAX_BARS_BACK = 20
indicator("Last high",overlay=true)

lookbackInput = input.int(5, minval = 1, maxval = MAX_BARS_BACK)
hi = ta.highest(lookbackInput)

hline(37.20, title="Higiest Value Last 50 Bars", color=color.green, linestyle=hline.style_solid,linewidth = 1)
hline(37.12, title="Higiest Closed Value Last 50 Bars", color=color.black, linestyle=hline.style_solid,linewidth = 1)
hline(35.78, title="Lowest Value Last 50 Bars", color=color.red, linestyle=hline.style_solid,linewidth = 1)
hline(35.96, title="Lowest Closed Value Last 50 Bars", color=color.black, linestyle=hline.style_solid,linewidth = 1)
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `line.new()` function can take a series float as a `y` argument. You can create new line, and delete previous lines to get the effect you want:

```
//@version=5
MAX_BARS_BACK = 20
indicator("Last high",overlay=true)

lookbackInput = input.int(5, minval = 1, maxval = MAX_BARS_BACK)
hi = ta.highest(lookbackInput)

myLine = line.new(bar_index - 1, hi, bar_index, hi, extend = extend.both)
line.delete(myLine[1])
```

If you want to get the highest or lowest `close` value, you can use the `source` parameter in the `ta.highest()` or `ta.lowest()` functions:

```
//@version=5
MAX_BARS_BACK = 20
indicator("Last high",overlay=true)

lookbackInput = input.int(5, minval = 1, maxval = MAX_BARS_BACK)
hi = ta.highest(close, lookbackInput)
lo = ta.lowest(close, lookbackInput)

hiLine = line.new(bar_index - 1, hi, bar_index, hi, extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
line.delete(hiLine[1])

loLine = line.new(bar_index - 1, lo, bar_index, lo, extend = extend.both, color = color.red)
line.delete(loLine[1])
```

Comment: Can i ignore last 5 bars ?